# На чем писать авторитарный сервер?

Tags: unity3d, сервер, клиент-сервер

. 
Доброго времени суток, уважаемые. Обращаюсь я к вам сегодня за советом.

Занимаемся мы с товарищами написанием небольшой пошаговой сетевой игры с гексагональным полем.
Пишем на Unity и основной каркас уже готов, вот только упёрлись в выбор того, на чём писать итоговый вариант сервера.
Вот и пришёл я сюда с надеждой, что, вы, господа, сможете пояснить мне за возможные технологии, их плюсы и минусы.

На данный момент сетевая часть работает через фотон, а сервер реализован, через запуск отдельного билда нашего проекта.
Вся директивная логика крутится на сервере, а клиент выступает исключительно, как виджет.
Другими словами клиент умеет рассчитывать путь по текущему полю и показывать его игроку, умеет понимать когда игрок может атаковать и куда игрок может пойти, но вот чтобы пойти - ему нужна команда от сервера.
Т.е. игрок жмёт на клетку и на сервер уходит сообщение "я хочу вот отсюда пойти сюда",  сервер проводит валидацию ввода и только после этого рассылает команду на отображения передвижения всем клиентам.

С нашей точки зрения, такой механизм - это идеальный вариант, чтобы избежать любого вмешательства в геймплей со стороны читеров.

Итоговый вопрос крутится вокруг того, на чем же нам лучше делать сервер? 
Какой-то готовый серверный движок? kbengine? NoahGameFrame? Nakama? BigWorld (его вообще получить ещё можно)? Свой сервер на C++? И присыпать всё это сверху логикой на скриптовом языке?
Или может быть использование C#? И сервер на нем и игровую логику? Переписать на чистую текущий фотоновский мастер-сервер?

Вариантов много и многих я даже не знаю. Надеюсь, что кто-то из читающих сможет подсказать.

Понятно, что при нагрузке в 100 человек разницы не будет. Но вот как себя поведут разные подходы при нагрузке в 10 000, 100 000? Миллион?

Мы, конечно, реалисты, но в стрессовом режиме не хотелось бы потом всё переписывать.

Возможно, кто-то сможет дать ссылки или краткое описание подходов. В какую сторону копать? Какие технологии посмотреть? У каких языков/подходов какие плюсы и минусы в плане производительности, нагрузок на железо, масштабируемости, разносу серверов на разные регионы, но с общей базой?

Comment: Ну если требований нет, то можно писать на чем умеете.

Comment: @VTT, а что за требования могут быть?

Comment: Ну как: производительность, железо, платформа, легкость масштабирования, легкость интеграции и т.п. Вот замашка на миллион пользователей - это конечно амбициозно, но вы уверены что их наберете? А если реальных требований по высокой производительности нет, так наверное имеет смысл не заморачиваться, и писать, на чем удобнее.

Comment: @VTT, нет, совсем не уверены) но иначе какой смысл начинать? Возможности и по продвижению и по разработке имеются. Только не понятно кого искать на сервер. Вот и провисаем. Не совсем ясно какие есть варианты и чем каждый из них хорош или плох.

Comment: А в таком виде вопрос неимоверно широк... Вариантов масса, небольшой сервер для небольшой игры можно написать почти на чем угодно, причем не упираясь с ходу в ограничения выбранного подхода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Редкий случай не простой темы с простым ответом. 
Технологий вагон на все вкусы и каждый день появляются новые. 
Лучшая та, которой владеете уже сейчас, на которую не потребуется дополнительное время изучения, инвестиции одним словом.

Здесь принцип KISS самое оно.

Амбиции в миллионы пользователей это здорово, но рабочий проект который работает на десяток тысяч вчера гораздо лучше возможно работающего который может поддерживать миллион через.. неделю? месяц?
Не заморачивайтесь ранней оптимизацией, она излишна.

Что касается конкретных предложений:

- Чем раньше уйдете от завязки сервера на юнити, тем лучше (тем более как я понял с физикой дела не имеете, так что проблем быть не должно)
- Отсюда второй пункт, чем скорее за логику игры отвечать будет один и тот же код на сервере и на клиенте

> Другими словами клиент умеет рассчитывать путь по текущему полю и показывать его игроку,

тем лучше будет и спокойней.

- Покрывайте, хотя бы базовую логику тестами, время окупится втройне.
- И последний общий совет, запускайтесь как можно раньше, не забывайте про аналитику итп.

Comment: Другими словами, коль уж собираемся переписывать сервер, то проще написать общую либу с логикой и использовать её и на сервере и на клиенте, но при этом сам сервер писать на том, на чем умеем. И переписывать его только, если внезапно разрастемся и будет не хватать мощностей. На данный момент просто собираемся искать серверника, и таким образом искать не какого-то конкретного спеца, а человека, который шарит в авторитарных выделенных серверах, а вопрос технологии сути не имеет?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. С маленькой поправкой, желательно, но не обязательно, придерживаться одного технологического стека. Это может упростить портирование и коммуникацию.

Comment: в приложении к нам - у нас Unity-C# клиент, соответственно сервер и либу логики делаем на C#, коль уж взялись за него) а на перспективу сервер переписываем на C++, а он продолжает так же использовать логику из либы

Comment: Звучит как план.